# Where can I find the meaning of NUnit console exit codes?

Tags: msbuild, nunit, nunit-console

I am getting error message from my MSBuild:

> "nunit-console.exe" exited with code -100.

Where can the meaning of the NUnit console exit codes be found?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`Error code -100` stands for [`UNEXPECTED_ERROR`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~nunit-core/nunit-3.0/trunk/view/head:/NUnitConsole/src/nunit-console/ConsoleRunner.cs#L41)

```
static ConsoleUi()
{
    OK = 0;
    INVALID_ARG = -1;
    FILE_NOT_FOUND = -2;
    FIXTURE_NOT_FOUND = -3;
    TRANSFORM_ERROR = -4;
    UNEXPECTED_ERROR = -100;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Additional information from [a thread on the NUnit-Discuss google group](http://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/d415e17b074e821a?pli=1):

> Additionally, positive values give a
>   count of failed tests in the run.
>
> The -100 return code is a catch-all,
>   usually indicating an unhandled
>   exception in your application or test.
>   It should normally come with a stack
>   trace.

Comment: Hmmm, I get -1 even though the runner runs and says nothing about an invalid arg...The source doesn't tell me either, tbh

Comment: Same here, our unit tests have been running fine in our continuous integration server fine, until recently (unfortunately I can;t identify what checking caused the issue)

Comment: I just found out (the hard way) that Error Code -2147023895 stands for StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 14):

A minor update as of NUnit v3, the `TRANSFORM_ERROR` code appears to have been removed.

The full list now stands as:

```
OK = 0;
INVALID_ARG = -1;
INVALID_ASSEMBLY = -2;
FIXTURE_NOT_FOUND = -3;       //Reserved, but not in use since v3.0
INVALID_TEST_FIXTURE = -4;    //From v3.4
UNEXPECTED_ERROR = -100;
```

The source for this is currently located [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/master/src/NUnitConsole/nunit3-console/ConsoleRunner.cs).

UPDATE: Five years on, we finally [documented](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Runner.html#console-exit-codes) these. Hooray!

Answer (score 2):

For those looking at this a number of years after the OP, these values have changed and changed again. In 3.8, there is a **-5 Unload Exception**, which is really handy to trap (when NUnit encounters a problem Unloading the assemblies). It seems that -5 is gone in 3.10. Perhaps the assembly Unload problem no longer occurs.